# How to create a Pandas DataFrame out of the keys from this JSON file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, parsing, dictionary

I have a csv file containing data in JSON structure and I want to create a dataframe out of it in a manner that all the keys become the column names and values the respective row values. Here's the csv file:

```
                                              events
0  {'id': 1245067280.0, 'eventId': 2, 'minute': 0
1  {'id': 1613373260.0, 'eventId': 2, 'minute': 0
2  {'id': 1560174527.0, 'eventId': 3, 'minute': 0
3  {'id': 1470954990.0, 'eventId': 4, 'minute': 0
4  {'id': 1628268979.0, 'eventId': 5, 'minute': 0
```

And here's what I want to create from this:

```
            id  eventId minute
0 1245067280.0  2        0
1 1613373260.0  2        0
2 1560174527.0  3        0
3 1470954990.0  4        0
4 1628268979.0  5        0
```

There are more key-value pairs but for the sake of brevity, I have only included three, `id`, `eventId`, and `minute`

What I've already tried is `df.from_records()` but that didn't change anything. Is there a Pandas/JSON function that allows this change easily or do people write code for this?

I've gone through many answers on here before posting and couldn't find anything specific to this. Most answers talk about creating a `Dictionary` from the JSON file and then converting to `Series`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file and convert the rows into a list of dicts (parsing `json` strings) before dropping all into a DataFrame, eg.:

```py
import csv
import json

with open('path_to_csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ') # Assuming values in your file are separated with a space
    next(reader) # Skip header row
    records = [json.loads(row[1]) for row in reader] # Assuming that json strings are in the second column of the csv file

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Comment: It gives me two errors: a) 'sep' is an invalid keyword arg and b) rows is not defined. What should I define rows as since the list comprehension doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sry, `rows` was a typo, meant `reader`, also `sep` should be `delimiter`. Updated my answer.

Comment: That solved that issue but there's a JSONDecode Error this time: `Expecting value: line 1 column 1(char 0)` What does this mean?

Comment: Include the first few rows of your file in the question (the actual content, not how you see after trying to read it in pandas). Most likely the csv reader splits the rows at the wrong points.

Comment: What's the standard procedure here for sharing csv files etc? I could send it to you if you want to look at the entire thing

Comment: Wait, might it be because the column has a header called "event" which is not JSON structure at all?

Comment: Actually, I just deleted the row myself and turns out the parser is expecting " " " while all my keys are " ' "

Comment: Not valid json then. Probably warrants a new question.

Comment: That's weird because I remember doing json.load() and it gave no errors then. That does mean it was valid JSON, right?

Comment: Here to report success, Cap. I found and replaced all the single quotes with double quotes and then replaced the Boolean False and True to "False" and "True" (because that was another error) and that worked out just fine